# Creating overlays for different apps in OSX

Tags: swift, macos

I want to create an app for OSX which would work as an addon (displaying some overlaying information) to other app. Something like Poker Tracker for example - it shows extra information for poker games while playing on tables.

Just wondering is it possible using Swift? Can you point me to some direction what to look for? some libraries helping with such case? Never developed anything for OSX but keen to learn.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you plan to write both the "add-on" application and the one being added to? If not, does the one to which you want to add functionality provide some sort of interface for that? If not, how do you plan to have your add-on app interact with it?

Comment: @Caleb No its a different app. As far as I know it doesn't expose any API, so it would need to be image scraped.  It would just display some extra text information based on the scraped data

Answer (score 0):

> Just wondering is it possible using Swift?

Yes, you can use Swift to create macOS applications. It's not magic, though -- your Swift code can only do things that are actually possible.

> Can you point me to some direction what to look for?

Look for an API that lets other apps interact with the host application. That API will define what your "add on" application can reasonably do.

Without some sort of API or scripting interface, it's going to be very difficult to write a program that interacts with the host application. The best option is probably the [Accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/accessibility/macos/) API in macOS. Accessibility is meant as an assistive technology, but it's often repurposed for tasks like automated testing. You might be able to use it to gain some level of control over the host app.

> As far as I know it doesn't expose any API, so it would need to be image scraped.

This is really a tall order, and doubly so if you're asking basic questions about language capabilities. I think you'd have much better luck creating an efficient user interface so that the user could enter the relevant information directly, e.g. what cards the other users are showing, bet sizes, etc.